# compression API for C++

Tags: c++, unix, compression

i am making an application which first compresses a file and then transfer it. I am using C++ as language in UNIX environment. I am unable to find any suitable library for my need. I checked but couldn't find any API for gunzip. Similarly 7zip also has SDK for windows only. It would be great if the library could provide percentage completed/left while the compression is in progress.

I read about Gzstream Library which is a wrapper of Zlib and also Boost IOStreams.

Please suggest the alternatives (if any) or the pros and cons of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) or [bzip2](http://bzip.org/) - Easy to use and well tested. bzip2 tends to compress better, zlib tends to be faster. Or you could use [QuickLZ](http://www.quicklz.com/) if speed matters most of all.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding the overhead of wxWidgets, in exchange for convenience, you may want to look at [wxZlibOutputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxzlibinputstream.html#wxzlibinputstream) and [wxZlibInputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxzliboutputstream.html#wxzliboutputstream).

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of the 7z SDK to Linux/UNIX: [xz and liblzma](http://tukaani.org/xz/). It's in most recent Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Like Android Eve said, if you don't mind the overhead, there's also [POCO's Zip](http://pocoproject.org/docs/ZipUserGuide.html) component.